# Stay for the second half

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

I'm watching a basketball game on TV with a friend of mine at my place. When the first half ends my friend says he'd better be going. I want him to stay so I ask:

Are you sure you don't want to stay for the second half? (1)
/
Are you sure you don't want to stay and watch the second half? (2)

Question:

Does the first sentence mean the exact same as the second? Would the first sentence even be more natural than the second?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are watching TV, then yes, they mean the same thing. If you're not then see James' answer below.

Comment: This is not an English language question. Translation into your language would yield the same result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not an English language question.

Answer (score 1):

They have different meanings, the first one doesn't mention "watching".  But you could understand "watch the game" from context, so in context they mean the same.

(Imagine you had listened to the first half on the radio, then "stay for the second half" would be different from "stay and watch the second half")